# Question regarding NaCl equilibrium separation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, physical-chemistry

So I am tutoring someone later and one of the problems is from Eisberg/Resnick Ch 12.

> The potential energy $V$ of NaCl can be described emperically by $$V = \frac{-e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R}+Ae^{-R/\rho}$$
>   where $R$ is the internuclear separation.  The equilibrium separation of the nuclei $R_0$ is 2.4 A and the dissociation energy is 3.6 eV.  Calculate A and $\rho/R_0$.

My thought process is to just find $dV/dR$ at $R_0$ and set that equal to zero.  But I am not completely sure where the dissociation energy comes into play. Any help?

Comment: You have 2 equations here: $V(R=R_{0})=-3.6eV$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}R}|_{R=R_{0}}=0$

Answer (score 1):

The potential energy (or pair potential) given above consists of two parts, the attractive term and the repulsive term.
$$V=\underbrace{-\frac{e^{2}}{4\pi \varepsilon _{0}R}}_{atractive}+\underbrace{Ae^{-R/\rho}}_{repulsive}$$
The attractive term is Coulomb interaction between two charges and the repulsive term represents the fact that lower than certain distances because of the overlap of electron clouds (Pauli Exclusion Principle) the particles will start to repel. $A$ and $\rho$ in the repulsive term are adjustable constants and represent "compressibility" or "hardness" of particles.

Two solve your question you need to be aware of two facts.

1- At equilibrium, the force between the particles is zero, which leads to (as mentioned by others)
$$F\left ( R_0 \right )=\frac{\mathrm{d} V}{\mathrm{d} R}\Bigr|_{\substack{R=R_0=2.4\ Å}}=0$$
2- At equilibrium, the energy between the particles is equal to dissociation energy (to be precise one should say negative of dissociation energy), which leads to (as mentioned by others)
$$V\left ( R_0 =2.4\ Å\right )=3.6\ eV$$

Once you have these two equations you can calculate both $A$ and $\rho$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two unknowns A and $\rho/R_0$. So you'll need two equations to solve for two unknowns. 
$V$ at equilibrium separation is the dissociation energy. After you find equilibrium separation, substitute in $V$ to get dissociation energy.

Comment: So do I still use the dV/dR =0 in addition?

Comment: Yeah. As I told you, you'll need two equations.